# UPS compatible with Linux box?

Tags: linux

I'm buying this unit from Deal Extreme: it's a [bitorrent downloader, with NAS capability](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.26320).

I'm interested in sharing an external HD with media and backup capabilities, although concerned about power related problems (don't know if this is the correct term), and the possible corruption of mounted drives (like after a storm). I thought about buying an UPS that sends a "signal" to my Linux box, and a script in my Linux box would unmount everything to avoid problems.

Do this "UPS signal" feature exists? Do you have model suggestions?

Comment: Is this "No Break" a real thing, or is it just the name you made up for something you want? Just asking because I never heard of it before and it sounds funny.

Comment: Ooops, you're right, this is the name we gave it here. Since it's in english I thought it would be the correct one. I'm editing it to "UPS". Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a UPS which will sustain the power to the system and drives, send a signal to a daemon on the system when power is interrupted and protect them from surges during "normal" power operation.

See [The UPS HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/UPS-HOWTO/)